# How would I remove all <script> tags (and everything in between) from multiple files using UNIX?

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I have a folder with multiple files, and I'd like to remove all `<script>` tags and everything in between, e.g.:

This:

```
<script type="text/javascript">function(foo);</script>
```

As well as this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

I think in PHP it would be something like this:

```
<?php $string = preg_replace('#(\n?<script[^>]*?>.*?</script[^>]*?>)|(\n?<script[^>]*?/>)#is', '', $string); ?>
```

But I'm at a loss when it comes to UNIX.

Comment: Are you only trying to remove the script tags, or all of the JavaScript in the document? Removing just the script tags still leaves a ton of ways that scripts can run; you can see a bunch of them here: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Comment: In this particular case, all of the JavaScript is between tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eg gawk

```
$ cat file
blah
<script type="text/javascript">function(foo);</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
blah
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="script1.js">
</script>
end

$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="</script>"}/<script/{gsub("<script.*","")}{print}END{if(RS=="")print}' file
blah




blah


end
```

so run it inside a for loop to go over your files(eg html)

```
for file in *.html
do
  awk 'BEGIN{RS="</script>"}/<script/{gsub("<script.*","")}{print}END{if(RS=="")print}' $file >temp
  mv temp $file
done
```

You can also do it with Perl,

```
perl -i.bak -0777ne 's|<script.*?</script>||gms;print' *.html
```

Comment: I went the perl route, and in the context of what I was trying to accomplish, it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only way you stand a chance of getting this right is to load the file (I'm assuming it's an HTML file) into a HTML/XML parser and remove the script nodes that way. Any other way will likely fall foul of the <script> tag containing "<script>" as part of its contents, for example:

```
<script>
    document.write('</script>');
</script>
```

Comment: Actually, browser DOM parsers will interpret that the same way the regular expression will--with the first </script> as the actual end of the script node. But using regular expressions on HTML is still a bad idea. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html

Comment: @Annie, Fair point, I was half aleep when I wrote that, but yeah, the "don't use regular expressions on HTML" bit still stands :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use something like [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tree) and remove all SCRIPT nodes as I walk the tree:

```
#!/usr/local/perls/perl-5.10.1/bin/perl

use 5.010;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $html = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
my $root = $html->parse_file( *DATA );

my @queue = ( $root->elementify );

while( my $element = shift @queue )
    {
    foreach ( $element->content_list )
        {
        when ( ! ref ) { 1 }
        when ( $_->tag eq 'script' )
            {
            $_->delete;
            }
        default
            {
            push @queue, $_
            }
        }
    }

print $html->as_HTML;

__END__
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is a title</title>
    <script>
    code section 1
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
    <script>
    code section 2
    </script>

<div>
    <script>
    code section 
    </script>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use perl to replace strings in many files.

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/search/replace/g;' *.html

-e means execute the following line of code.
-i means edit in-place
-w write warnings
-p loop
```

You'll have to come up with the regex on your though. (The one you have should work.)

Comment: The asker also wishes to locate <script> and </script> and everything in between.

Comment: Uh, yeah, without correcting for escaped characters, <script>.*<script> does exactly that. It'll need fine tuning to make sure the correct closing tag is select (For greediness)

Answer (score -1):

well you can run PHP from the commandline, or translate that line pretty easily into perl (the "p" in "preg_replace"). You could use sed to do something similar, but the regexes aren't as flexible. Regexes may or may not be good enough depending on where your input is coming from and what your goal is.